# How to remove bitmap object from memory?

Tags: android, android-bitmap

Need little help, i'm loading an image from external storage and then saving in an bitmap object, after doing some work on bitmap object, and when i'm done with it, i'm setting bitmap object equal to null (bitmap= null) , now my question is , will "equating bitmap to null", removes it from memory or not, if not then how to remove it from memory.

Comment: Try reading the documentation of Bitmap.

Comment: Glide or not, whether you set bitmap to null or invoke bitmap.recylce() it depends on GC threads the memory. This has been asked many times in different threads, memory used for bitmap is not cleared instantly. I build camera apps and never found a way to dispose memory from bitmap until GC decides to remove it. You can search for it in SO.

Answer (score 0):

Glide is officially supported library by google. you  can read this [doc](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/manage-memory.html). On top section it is written that

> For most cases, we recommend that you use the Glide library to fetch, decode, and display bitmaps in your app. Glide abstracts out most of the complexity in handling these and other tasks related to working with bitmaps and other images on Android. For information about using and downloading Glide, visit the Glide repository on GitHub.

you can find glide repo here [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) .